# Spring Security: WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.class not found

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-security

I am having an issue with Spring Security. I am trying to configure it for a simple login but I am getting an error. Here is the code for the configuration:

```
package com.drg.AppConfig;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

/**
 * Created by me on 09-Aug-17.
 */

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and()
                .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER","ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/program/").access("hasRole(ROLE_USER')")
                .antMatchers("/admin").access("hasRole(ROLE_ADMIN')")
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

}
```

And here is the error:

```
09-Aug-2017 16:39:24.658 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.refresh Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.drg.AppConfig.SecurityConfiguration]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
09-Aug-2017 16:39:24.670 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.drg.AppConfig.SecurityConfiguration]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:181)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:308)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4745)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1702)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:431)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)



Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:50)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:98)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:693)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getSuperClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:857)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:328)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:167)
    ... 54 more
```

For Spring Security I've added the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Could someone please help me find a solution here? How can I avoid the exception I am getting. Please be aware that the class is downloaded from the maven dependency.

Comment: Could do you verify in your m2 repository if you have the jar spring-security-config-4.2.3-RELEASE.jar? Also I have a similar configuration but I dont use the Configuration and EnableWebSecurity in the class

Comment: in your ide  see maven  dependencies  and check if spring-security jar is added and has class inside it

Comment: You say the class has been downloaded due to the dependency but are you sure? Similar to what others have said, have you done a `mvn clean install` in the project directory and have seen the dependency get downloaded from the maven repository?

Comment: I have don the `mvn clean install` and seen the jars downloaded. have to mention that i've checked the IDE and they were downloaded before, also. hmm ..strugling with this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved: It seems like the spring security libraries were not added to the artifact in the project build configuration. Also I've changed the `SecurityConfiguration` class body with:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and()
        .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER","ADMIN");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/admin").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
        .and().formLogin();
        http.csrf().disable();
}
```

I've added the initializer class witch extends `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer`

```
package com.dragos.config;

import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

Answer (score 8):

add proper spring security libraries.if still not working make sure to clean your tomcat directory

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: How to fix this error in gradle project?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Springboot, you need to be using Spring-starter-security.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

otherwise you will get the error you encountered.

If you are using Spring MVC these would be correct

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Spring Security 5.7.0-M2, WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter deprecated, As per the [Springboot Docs](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter), they want to encourage users to move towards a component-based security configuration.

Please  read in  the details [here](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter)

Answer (score 1):

please add this below dependency to start working with Spring Security

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

if you are using spring Security above 5.7.0-M2, spring has deprecated the class WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

please refer below link to use spring security without WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

[spring security without WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. I tried all the methods in the above answers.

I first added all the dependencies listed above, then stopped the running server, then update the maven project, then restarted the server.

Answer (score -1):

For future folks looking at this thread... clearing your IDE cache and restarting your IDE might help.  It did the trick for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).